# How to prevent multiple objects in Java Game from slowing down the game

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

I am creating a bullet hell game where the player tries to dodge all the bullets on screen. My current game loop updates all the objects on the screen using multiple for loops in multiple methods.

Since this is a bullet hell game, there are could be up to hundreds of bullets on screen at the same time. Also I have a method called checkCollisions that checks if the sprite of a bullet over laps a player. Due to this, the game usually starts lagging when the amount of bullets reaches over a hundred bullets because its essentially iterating over the list of bullets twice.

I thought about using running a thread on the side to update the positions of the bullets and to check the collisions. The code is shown below. Each thread essentially just calls the update methods in the main game class. However, this just made the game lag more at lower bullet numbers. I'm not sure if this is because I'm creating new thread classes or for some other reason. Or maybe it is because of all the concurrentModification errors the program is throwing.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (inGame) {
        updateEnemies();
        projectileChecker = new Thread(new checkProjectiles(this));
        projectileChecker.start();
        //updateProjectiles();
        updateBags();
        updateCharacter();
        //checkCollisions();
        collisionChecker = new Thread(new checkCollision(this));
        collisionChecker.start();
        repaint();
    }

}
```

Currently I've thought of 4 ways to solve this.

1. Continue with the thread method but (1) Use a thread executor to stop defining new threads, or (2) use a while loop inside the thread to call the method so don't have to define new threads (This seems to break the code, bullets show on screen but no longer move/disappear)
2. Combine update projectiles and collision checker, this seems like doing twice the work for half the iterations, which doesn't seem like it will make much of a difference
3. Stop repainting after every call of update projectile/collision check, only repaint at 60 fps or something like that.
4. Stop drawing the background image every time it repaints. (Not that useful due to in the future would want to create a camera object that follows the player around a bigger map)

I've tried the first two and the code just doesn't work, and I have no idea how to approach the last 2. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Unrelated note, a profiler is showing the number of active threads increasing constantly through the runtime of the program. Maybe that has an effect? Also, shows that a majority of the time is taken by paintComponent.

Comment: Consider a data structure for your onscreen objects that allows you to only check for collisions if they are “close” to each other.

Comment: So do I just look for projectiles that are within a certain range of another object and then run check collision for them?

Comment: Weirdly enough, the game seems to lag hard on the second wave for no reason, then resume speed in the next few waves, and then lag slightly in larger waves. Weird because the 2nd wave is not big at all, and there are not alot of objects on the screen. The third wave has way more objects(bullets enemies, etc) but doesnt lag as hard as wave 2

Comment: Something like that.  It is not uncommon to do tricks to avoid doing unnecessary work.  Regarding your lag problem, consider looking at your application while running with a profiler like visualvm to see what it is doing.

Comment: Yep thats exactly what Ive been doing

It seems like the majority of the time taken in the profiler is by AWT EventQueue 0. In the profiler portion of VisualVM, AWT is using 24000 ms and the next item on the list is a thread that is using only 178ms. Among the AWT methods, paintcomponent is using 20k ms

Comment: What I really dont understand is why Wave 2 lags so much compared to the 50+ other waves. Wave 2 plays out at like 1/2 speed whereas the other slight laggy waves play out at maybe 9/10 speed

Comment: I seemed to have fixed the lag problem with larger amounts of projectiles. I was creating copys of both the arraylists for projectiles in my check collisions code to get around the concurrent modifications problem (which I already solved), after i removed the copy the lag with larger amounts of projectiles is way lesser, however lag on wave 2 is still there

Comment: Profile.  Find out where the time is spent.

Comment: And if the paint method takes too long, you may invoke it too often.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238825/discussion-between-bill-zhang-and-thorbjorn-ravn-andersen).